# Apply function to dataframe column of lists

Tags: pandas, nlp

I have a set of text strings (A). I can break them down into tokens (B). I would like to drop some of the tokens so that I end up with only words (C). I tried:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["potato soup, 99", "2 tomato"]})

# Tokenise
df['B'] = df['A'] .apply(word_tokenize)

# Words only
def Words(Token):
    if Token .isalpha():
        return Token
df['C'] = df['B'] .apply(Words)
```

But I got an error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isalpha'

I am applying the function to the lists but I would like to apply it to the things in the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y.isalpha()])
```